# IndexError in this code

Tags: python, indexing, file-access

When I use this as the contents of the input file:

```
1,3,5,7,9,11
```

I receive this error:

```
IndexError: li
```

---

```
with open('fig.fig') as o:
    n = 6
    for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):
        print(o.readlines()[i].replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

there is nothing wrong with the following code:

```
n = 6  
for i in range(1, 2*n, 2):  
    print <something>[i].replace(' ', '')
```

so the problem is in the open or reading of your file (really open? line length?). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When opening and processing a file, you should always make sure that you don't attempt to read more lines than are actually in the file. Also, you are making repeated calls to `readlines` which is quite inefficient. Try something like:

```
with open('fig.fig') as o:    
    lines = o.readlines()
    n=6
    for i in range(1, min(len(o), n*2), 2):
       print(lines[i].replace(' ', ''))
```

This will read odd numbered lines, up to n*2, or the maximum number of lines in the file, whichever is less. You should also check that the file exists (one way is to use `os.path.isfile('fig.fig')`, or wrap everything in a [try](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) block.